# Como fazer com que várias labels fiquem com um número gerado aleatoriamente

Tags: c#

Eu estou a fazer um jogo de Bingo. Onde tenho 4 cartões e cada cartão tem 15 labels (15 números). Eu quero que quando o form inicie, cada label tenha um número gerado aleatoriamente. No entanto, só estou a conseguir fazer com que UMA label fique com um número aleatório.

Isto é o que eu tenho:

```
foreach (Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next(100).ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar a variável **lbl** dentro do foreach, pois ela irá representar cada label do seu form.

Além disso, é recomendado que você crie a instância da classe Random fora do seu laço, pois você corre o risco de gerar os mesmos números repetidamente, além de problemas de desempenho.

> Inicializar dois geradores de números aleatórios em um loop estreito,
>   ou em sucessão rápida cria dois geradores de números aleatórios que
>   podem produzir idênticas sequências de números aleatórios. Na maioria
>   dos casos, isso não é intenção do desenvolvedor e pode levar a
>   problemas de desempenho, como instanciar e inicializar um gerador de
>   número aleatório são um processo relativamente caro.

[Fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2#avoiding-multiple-instantiations)

Outro ponto dado o seu contexto, você está fazendo um bingo, então não existe o número 0 na cartela. O mais recomendado para você gerar os números aleatórios é usar da seguinte maneira, pois o seu código tem a chance de gerar o número 0.

O código final ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

foreach (Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {    
            lbl.Text = rnd.Next(1, 100).ToString(); // Irá gerar um número de 1 até 99
        }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente faz mais sentido usar dessa forma. Agradeço imenso, ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 2):

A explicação do @LeonardoL ficou muito boa para seu problema! Porém irei deixar um código adicional para resolver um outro tipo de problema caso ocorra no seu cenário.

O cenário do Leonardo irá funcionar muito bem caso todas suas labels estejam dentro do formulário como controle primário, caso elas sejam filhas de algum outro controle, como por exemplo, um *Panel* (elas estejam dentro de um panel), você não irá conseguir encontra-las no seu `foreach`.

Para resolver esse cenário, precisamos criar um método recursivo que irá navegar todos os controles da nossa tela, até o último nível, procurar por todas as labels contidas nesse formulário e definir um novo valor para a propriedade `Text`:

```
public void DefinirValorLabels(Control control, Random random)
{
    // Se nosso controle for uma label, definimos a propriedade "Text" como um número aleatório
    if (control is Label)
        control.Text = random.Next(1, 100).ToString();

    // Se o controle não é uma label, ele pode ser um panel (por exemplo), ou seja, dentro desse controle (panel) pode haver outras labels.
    // Por esse motivo, iremos percorrer nosso controle e ver se possuimos mais labels para definirmos um valor.
    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        DefinirValorLabels(ctrl, random);
    }
}
```

Para utilizar, basta chamar o método da seguinte maneira:

```
Random random = new Random();
DefinirValorLabels(this, random);
```

Comment: Acho que no futuro irei precisar disso, agradecido!